# ConstraintLayout Flow wrapping

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-flow

I want to show an unknown number of elements (more than 1, less than 15) in a specific order as it is shown by the following image.
[image]

The elements **G** and **H** should not be shown to the user. The area should not be scrollable as well. The rendering should done the way the arrows point.

The *xml* file for the layout is the following

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_mini_games_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:background="@color/black_transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/gl_center">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                    android:id="@+id/flow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="mini_game_1, mini_game_2, mini_game_3, mini_game_4, mini_game_5, mini_game_6, mini_game_7, mini_game_8"
                    app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
                    app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
                    app:flow_verticalBias="0"
                    app:flow_maxElementsWrap="2"
                    app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
                    app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                </androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_1"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_2"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_3"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_4"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_5"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_6"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_7"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mini_game_8"
                    layout="@layout/item_casino_mini_game" />




            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `item_casino_mini_game` is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/mini_casino_game_tile_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/mini_casino_game_tile_size"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/g600"
    tools:cardBackgroundColor="@color/prize_full_bet"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/row_themed_casino_game_category">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_mini_game"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The weird thing is that I achieve the following result:
[image]

As you can see the elements **G** and **H** are partially visible to user. How can I achieve to show **no partially rendered items** (**G** and **H** for this scenario) without resizing the parent element's width nor the child elements (A, B, C, ...) size?

*I would prefer to do it with a `ConstraintLayout Flow` but any other solution is more than welcome.*

Comment: If you don't change the container width or the item widths, then the only other thing to change is the item spacing.

Comment: @Cheticamp is it possible to be auto-calculated by the `ConstraintLayout Flow` and keep the G, H items out of sight?

Comment: I think that you would need to calculate the gap. See [setHorizontalGap(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#setHorizontalGap(int)).